# Is Version annotation of Spring Data thread safe for Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I'm wondering if I annotate the "version" field of the POJO with @Version, will the increment operation be thread-safe?

I want to be sure about Spring Data Mongodb makes use of Mongodb's atomic operations while incrementing the version along with setting the rest of the object.